# How to convert Native sql in hibernate Query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a requirement where in i would like to convert my Native query into an hql,Hibernate is pretty new to me so any help will be of great help.

```
   SELECT DISTINCT a.sales_order_id, c.name 
    FROM sales_order a
      LEFT JOIN sales_order_Account b ON a.sales_order_id=b.sales_order_id
     LEFT JOIN account c ON b.account_id=c.account_id AND c.account_type_id=2
    LEFT JOIN sales_order_Account d ON a.sales_order_id=d.sales_order_id
   LEFT JOIN account e ON d.account_id=e.account_id AND e.account_type_id=1
    ORDER BY c.name DESC
```

here the sales account,Account and account type are coming from different class and table( but they are joined with account id and account type id with sales_order_id

i am trying to use this in an DaoImpl class to get the required value.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [the Java EE 7 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/persistence-querylanguage.htm#BNBTG) as an introduction to JPQL (of which HQL is a superset). In JPQL/HQL, you often select entity objects in themselves instead of columns from tables, and instead of manually joining tables, you access entity attributes. So you might have something like

`SELECT a FROM SalesOrder a WHERE a.account.type = 2 AND ...`